# Julia : How to fill a matrix row by row in julia

Tags: matrix, vector, julia

I have 200 vectors; each one has a length of 10000.

I want to fill a matrix such that each line represents a vector.

Answer (score 4):

If your vectors are already stored in an array then you can use `vcat( )` here:

```
A = [rand(10000)'  for idx in 1:200]
B = vcat(A...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Julia stores matrices in column-major order so you are going to have to adapt a bit to that

If you have 200 vectors of length 100000 you should make first an empty vector, a = [], this will be your matrix
Then you have to vcat the first vector to your empty vector, like so

```
v = your vectors, however they are defined 
a = []
a = vcat(a, v[1])
```

Then you can iterate through vectors 2:200 by

```
for i in 2:200
    a = hcat(a,v[i])
end
```

And finally transpose a

```
a = a'
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
a = zeros(200,10000)

for i in 1:length(v)
    a[i,:] = v[i]
end
```

but I suppose that wont be as fast, if performance is at all an issue, because as I said, julia stores in column major order so access will be slower

**EDIT** from  reschu's comment

```
a = zeros(10000,200)

for i in 1:length(v)
    a[:,i] = v[i]
end 

a = a'
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the second version is faster. Concatenation will resize array `a` at each iteration. Anyway, you can preallocate a 10000x200 matrix, loop over the columns, and transpose it afterwards. If you want to be certain: time it.